# Split String to Array and do a like to match value in another column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two columns to compare in a MYSQL table and wanted to split the value of first column to an array and look for any of these values in arrays matches with the values in array of second columns. Here is an example:

```
Column1                     Column2
Walmart Supercenter         Walmart Sams
Home                        Home Depot
3M Logistics Co.            3M
```

if my approach is something like this then it will never match

```
column2 like concat('%',column1,'%')
```

What I am looking for:

```
column2 like concat('%',column1[0],'%') or column2 like concat('%',column1[1],'%')
```

Comment: Could there ever be more than two values in either column?  Could one of the two columns have only a single value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes  either of these column could have One and more values, not restricted to two. Updated the Question

Comment: Then my answer is that you should fix your table design.  If each word is a piece of information, then store each word in a separate row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yes looks like either the way you suggested or using a server side language Python/PHP etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

> - use `custom split_str` funciton get column1[0] and column1[1]
> - `.. like .. or ..` use REGEXP + `|`

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (`Column1` varchar(19), `Column2` varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO T
    (`Column1`, `Column2`)
VALUES
    ('Walmart Supercenter', 'Walmart Sams'),
    ('Home', 'Home Depot'),
    ('3M Logistics Co.', '3M')
;

CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

---

**Query**

```
select *
from T
where `Column2` REGEXP 
case when SPLIT_STR(`Column1`, ' ', 2) = '' then
    SPLIT_STR(`Column1`, ' ', 1)
else 
    concat(
      SPLIT_STR(`Column1`, ' ', 1) 
      ,'|'
      ,SPLIT_STR(`Column1`, ' ', 2)
    )  
end;

| Column1             | Column2      |
| ------------------- | ------------ |
| Walmart Supercenter | Walmart Sams |
| Home                | Home Depot   |
| 3M Logistics Co.    | 3M           |
```

---

### [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oDUJto9exj9YML2Enk3odh/2)

Although this way can be achieved, but the efficiency is not good

Comment: it fails for 2nd row in my Question (Home,Home Depot) because you cannot split Single value